# Does Windows Update run when Guest account is logged in?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, guest-account

Our other PC is primarily used for guests so the Guest account is logged on most of the time while the Admin account is rarely used.

Does Windows Update run on Guest Account? If not, is there a way to do this like can I logon first as Admin, switch (without logging off) to Guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will occasionally have to log on to the computer with the Administrator account (Windows XP) or log on with a user account that has administrator permissions. But if you enable automatic updates then updates will be installed automatically, even when a user is logged on with the Guest account.